# Log format not recognized in Pycharm

Tags: logging, pycharm

I have ideolog plugin installed in Pycharm and this is basic config of logging:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='my_log.log', level='DEBUG', format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(funcName)s:%(threadName)s:%(message)s')
```

When I open the log file in pycharm editor, it shows the content in white and an error message:

```
Log format not recognized
```

I want to see the logs in their respective colors. Any solution?

thanks in advance

Comment: It's better to ask in its issue tracker https://github.com/JetBrains/ideolog/issues

Answer (score -3):

This might help https://medium.com/dev-genius/python-logging-basics-458ad969e850
I think you need to set the log level to the variable created
log = logging.getLogger(**file**) and you need to create a file handler if you want to log it in a file. Hope it solves